# Find The Last Value of Range With Criteria and Return Value of Another Cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I need to figure out the formula to get last messageid based on replyto within a threadid.

Below is an example. Basically the last instance of a messageid within a threadid I need to return the value of messageid in "Last Thread Post ID". My spreadsheet will always be sorted as shown.

The first post in a thread has a replyto number of 0.

I have a database with tens of thousands of messageid and threadid, so I can't do it manually like I did below. I'm not sure how to set up a formula or macro to perform this task. Any help is appreciated.

```
messageid   threadid    replyto    Last messageid in thread
3550        3550        0          3550
3867        3867        0          4677
3947        3867        3867        
3998        3867        3947        
4337        3867        3998        
4414        3867        4337        
4481        3867        4414        
4677        3867        3867        
3925        3925        0          7200
4653        3925        3925        
4959        3925        4653        
7200        3925        3925        
4092        4092        0          4092
5800        5800        0          5800
5802        5802        0          5802
7202        7202        0          7202
7203        7203        0          7656
7294        7203        7203        
7305        7203        7203        
7342        7203        7203        
7406        7203        7342        
7436        7203        7305        
7656        7203        7203
```

Comment: well... I wanna understand what do you want to expect as the result, so correct me if I'm wrong. Between treadid 3867, you expected the result is messageid 4481 because the id in replayto is 4414(max)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this in D2 and copy down:

```
=IF(C2=0,AGGREGATE(14,6,$A$2:$A$24/($B$2:$B$24=B2),1),"")
```

[image]

Comment: What if I had text in col. E, is there a formula that would figure out what the last text within a threadid? So same thing, just not a number but text.

Comment: BTW: You are saving my life here. I am very appreciative of your help, Scott. You are a saint.

Comment: It will take an array INDEX/MATCH formula, But that is a new question with a new test data set.  It is definitely possible.

Comment: I'm sorry for being daft, but you want me to start a new question? I'm cool with it, just want to be sure.

Comment: Yup, what you are asking is what we refer to a Russian doll situation.  Each question deserves its own question.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for being patient with this noob.